# Google Drive document parent folder link missing after update

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, document-management

After a recent update of Google Drive, we can no longer navigate to the folder containing the open document. The below image shows what the folder dialog used to look like. Clicking the folder link (shown as `Public` in the below screen shot) opened the folder in a new tab.

[image: Old folder dialog]

Unfortunately, the "new and improved" folder dialog does not allow for opening the document parent folder. And only allows for moving the document to a different location.

[image: New folder dialog]

Is there a way to get the old functionality back or is there a new/different way to open the documents parent folder?

Comment: No, I don't think this is possible any longer. You should post about it on Google's forums and request that they add it back (it wouldn't be a hard change from a developer's perspective)

Comment: This is killing me too. If there's such post on Google's forums where we can go and upvote, please share the link.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is about a former bug in Google's systems, that can no longer be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

Found a thread that seems to be being updated:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/FwXAmuDBPQ0/zF3K7Q8NAwAJ

Comment: Can you summarize what is at the link please.  If the link goes dead, the answer becomes worthless.